# How to count number of dots drawn on Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to understand Processing, so I'm doing some random stuff. I'm using code below and I want to draw and count the number of dots drawn on upper left side:

```
int clickx[] = new int[50];
int clicky[] = new int[50]; 
int mousx = 0;
int mousy = 0;
void setup() {
    size(860, 640);
    background(0);
    frameRate(30);
    mousx = mouseX;
    mousy = mouseY;
}
void draw() {
   if (mousePressed) {
      if (mousx != mouseX) {
          stroke(255);
          point(mouseX, mouseY);
          int i = 0;
          clickx[i] = mouseX;
          clicky[i] = mouseY;
          i++;
          text(i, 50, 50);
      }
   }
}
```

But instead I'm getting same number all the time:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` variable is always set to `0`.

Why are you using arrays if you only ever draw one dot at a time?

In either case, you need to increment a variable each time a dot is drawn, and then use that variable as the count. Here's a small example;

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1;
println(i); //prints 1
i = i + 1;
println(i); //prints 2
```

This code could be slightly shortened using the `++` increment operator:

```
int i = 0;
i++;
println(i); //prints 1
i++;
println(i); //prints 2
```